# How to downgrade all headers in a word file

Tags: microsoft-word

How to downgrade all headers? e.g. make all Header 4 becomes Header 5, Header 3 becomes Header 4 and so on. Of course this can be done manually one by one, but I wonder if there's an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more convenient way:

1. Mark all (Ctrl+A)
2. Demote (Alt+Shift+Right)

This demotes all outline elements, which are usually linked to the header styles.

These are the default accelerators used in Word 2010. You can also switch to the outline view (Ctrl+Alt+O by default, or click View and Outline – Alt, W, U), mark all, and in the "Outlining" ribbon select the single green right arrow (Alt, U, M). Get back to print view with Ctrl+Alt+P or to normal view with Ctrl+Alt+N.

Comment: It seems someone is downvoting all my posts indiscriminately. Please give me some advice if there is actually anything I could do to make my posts better, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find and replace styles.  Start with the highest number "4" and replace with "Heading 5".  Then replace Heading 3 with Heading 4 etc, as you have set out in your question above.

[image]

Comment: OK i guess this is the best way to do..